# What is Auth'n'auth?

Tags: authentication, oauth, ebay-api

Requesting my keys on developer.eBay, I see a message that invites me to enable OAuth. But the message also speaks about `Auth'n'auth`.

Searching for it on Google doesn't give me any information about what this is, so I'm asking here.

The complete message given to me by eBay is:

> To use eBay's latest security features, add OAuth security to your
>   keys. These keys will support both Auth'n'auth and OAuth.
>
> For keys with multiple redirect URLs go to the Tokens page and enable
>   one redirect URL for OAuth only. All redirect URLs will continue to
>   support Auth'n'auth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old post, and I also wondered as to what this meant.   It is apparently just eBay jargon for Authentication and Authorization or as eBay refers to it - Auth'n'Auth.

They have an eBay developer technical support article about this here - https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=1198

That article even shows an example usage:

```xml
<INPUT TYPE=\"submit\" NAME=AUTHORIZE VALUE=\"Launch Auth & Auth\" "
             .  "onclick=\"window.open('https://signin.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn&runame=$runame&SessID=$sessid');\">\n"
```